# Find who gets the maximum salary in each location

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I have two table as follows:

employ_offical:

```
id  name   salary
1   raj    5000
2   ram    8000
3   balu   3000
4   david  4000
```

employee personal:

```
name   location
raj      india
ram      china
balu     india
david    china
```

From these two tables, I need to know how to retrieve who gets maximum salary in every location; in one location one person should come under these category.

How to retrieve who gets maximum salary in every location?

Comment: Have you tried solving this problem yourself?

Comment: I added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. This type of question comes up frequently, so you can go read some of the many other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve this:

```
select p.location, p.name, o.salary
  from employ_offical o,
       employee_personal p
 where o.name = p.name
   and o.salary = (
       select max(o2.salary)
         from employ_offical o2,
              employee_personal p2
        where o2.name = p2.name
          and p2.location = p.location);
```

There is a SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59726/2).

Please note that I have joined on name here as it is the only join available, but from a design perspective it would be much better to have id in both tables and join on id.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT eo.name, ep.location, eo.salary 
FROM employ_offical eo
INNER JOIN employee_personal ep ON eo.name = ep.name
WHERE eo.salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) 
                   FROM employ_offical eo1 
                   INNER JOIN employee_personal ep1 ON eo1.name=ep1.name 
                   WHERE ep.location = ep1.location                        
                   )
```

It might not be the most efficient or pretty way to do this though.

Note that if multiple persons in the same location share the max salary for that location this query will return all of them.